# Login credential vs go to url

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I created a report on SSRS. And I created an action by using go to url within the report. The action calls the another report via url. But the reporting server login credential will be needed. Can I pass login credential within url to call the report on Microsoft Reporting Server?

PS: I cannot use go to report because I want to open the report in new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was answered previously on msdn,

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/569708ca-46a9-4b27-9fd0-f5ba929c2c9c/

hope it helps.